# WKInterfaceSKScene.Init() deprecated from WatchOS 6

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, watchkit

I recently converted my Storyboard SpriteKit WatchOS app from Storyboards to SwiftUI, in one part of my code I use the `WKInterfaceSKScene.texture` method to render some `SKNodes` to a texture for use later on in my game.

Unfortunately after the conversion you no longer have a `WKInterfaceSKScene` object as part of the view, but I realized that I can just create one using the `WKInterfaceSKScene.init()` initializer, this seems to work great, however, the init initializer is now deprecated and I assume will be removed in a future WatchOS version.

The warning is:

> 'init()' was deprecated in watchOS 7.0: Use SpriteKit.SpriteView instead.

Unfortunately SpriteView does not seem to have a similar method to render an `SKNode` to a texture.

I tried finding a different way of rendering `SKNodes` to a texture without using the `WKInterfaceSKScene` object but can’t find one, does anybody know how to do this on watchOS 9 without utilizing deprecated functionality?

WKInterfaceSKScene init() - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceskscene/3141929-init

WKInterfaceSKScene texture() -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceskscene/1650802-texture

Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, I am wondering if a potential workaround could be to use the SKEffectNode with the shouldRasterize property, as that may give me the same performance benefits without rendering the SKNode tree all the time, still, it seems wasteful to have all the nodes in memory when they aren’t needed - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skeffectnode/1459381-shouldrasterize

Answer (score 1):

in `SpriteKit` all visible nodes are automatically rendered into textures ([per documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode/getting_started_with_sprite_nodes))

> An SKTexture object is `created and attached to the node`. `This texture object automatically loads the texture data whenever the sprite node is in the scene`, is visible, and is necessary for rendering the scene. Later, if the sprite is removed from the scene or is no longer visible, SpriteKit can delete the texture data if it needs that memory for other purposes. This automatic memory management simplifies but does not eliminate the work you need to do to manage art assets in your game.

Comment: Sorry this does not answer my question, I need to render an SKNode tree into a texture to avoid having to render hundreds nodes later on which will slow the app down, I looked deeper into the documentation I found that there is another way using texture(from:), but alas, it is not available on watchOS: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1519994-texture so I still do not have a resolution for this.